# Ubuntu installed on Vmware cannot get access to internet

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, vmware, vmware-player

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Vmware, the host machine is Windows 7. However, I cannot get access to internet from Ubuntu. I am not clear how to identify the cause and fix it? Thank you for the help.

This the screenshot I choose the option of "bridged" option. Besides, I also include the result of running ifconfig  [image]

[image]

I also try to change to "bridge option"

[image]

Comment: Have you installed VMware tools?

Comment: Yes, I have installed VMware tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to Bridge your actual Ethernet port to VmWare port, so that virtual machine get access to internet through that bridged connection.

In order to do that, instruction are available on following links:

**1.** [Configuring Bridged Networking Options on a Windows Host](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_changing_bridged_windows.html)

**2.** [Vmware Help](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_configure_ws.html)

This will definitely solve your issue.

**UPDATE**

For Vmware PLayer: **[How to Fix a VMware Player Bridged Network?](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/how-to-fix-a-vmware-player-bridged-network.html)**

There are images shown in the article, which will help you to attend each step.

Another resolution is it may be possible that it won't work with **Bridged Connection**. Try with **[NAT (N/W Address Translation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)** option.

if it still doesn't work then check your UBUNTU has correct driver installed.

For further information you can dive in following links...

1. 
[Troubleshooting networking and internet connection issues in VMware](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1016466)

2. 
[Understanding networking types in VMware](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1022264)

Comment: I use VMware player, and cannot follow the procedure listed in the link, which kind of related to VMware workstation.

Comment: Novice, thank you for your reply. I will try again.

Comment: No need to thank you, if it works, just check the grey mark.

Comment: I followed the step, and changed to bridge option. It still did not work. I included a screenshot in my previous post. The thing confused me is that three of four available adapters are virtual-box related. What does that mean? I did install virtualbox on windows host as well.

Comment: Do one thing only, select that check box that is just bellow to the Bridge Conn radio button. It'll replicate details to VM, so that UBUNTU will be able to use your HOST machine connection. And about other adapters that are showing, while installing VMware server /player it installs it's own Virtual Ports(bridge connections) to support inernet on VMs running on it.

Comment: Hi, I tried again as you suggested. The screenshot is updated in the original post. It still does not work.

Comment: Is that a "let me google that for you" answer? It does not explain anything.

Comment: In my case, to solved this issue, I went to **VMWare's Bridge Automatic Settings** and *unchecked* all unusable host network adapters, just left my wifi adapter (the one I was using to access Internet) *checked*.

Answer (score 5):

Selecting NAT option under Network Connection in Network Adapter setting has done the trick for me.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is an older post but none of these solutions worked for me so I thought I would share.

As some mentioned changed the adapter to NAT may fix the problem but for me I needed to be in bridged mode. Somehow my vmnet with the bridge configs was deleted but something was retained because it would not let me add another.

In vmware I went to `Edit>Virtual Network Editor` then at the bottom there is a button to switch to administrator mode. Click that then restore to factory defaults. This fixed all my vmnets.

Comment: This actually worked also in my case when I mistakenly deleted my interfaces inside the guest OS. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 3):

I tried everything everyone has posted to an unsuccessful outcome. Then, under the wifi icon on the Ubuntu upper right taskbar, I clicked "auto ethernet". BAM! Lit up like a christmas tree. Everything connected right away.