# Internet is not working on VM - Black Screen - Ubuntu 13.04/16.04 Guest and Windows 10 Host

Tags: networking, 13.04, windows, virtualbox

I am a Windows user and I followed these steps to install Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit on my Windows 10 64-bit:

- Install Oracle Virtual Box 5.1.2
- [Download Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit ISO Image File](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433087/ubuntu-32bit-13-04-iso-image-for-virtual-box)
- Create New Machine:

  - 1024 MB RAM
  - Create Virtual Hard Disk:

    - VDI
    - Fixed
    - 8 GB

Then I `Start` the machine, and it asks me for the location of the `.iso` file. I submit and it starts the setup. After some time, it finished and asks for restart.

**Problem:**

After it asks me for the login credentials, it pops several errors about needed updates but internet is not working. If I ignore(which I have no choice), I get full black screen:

[image]

**Attempts:**

**[Internet isn't working in Ubuntu 14.04 as VirtualBox Guest OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487114/internet-isnt-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-as-virtualbox-guest-os)** my settings match the answer's suggested settings.

**[Ubuntu installed on Vmware cannot get access to internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578260/ubuntu-installed-on-vmware-cannot-get-access-to-internet)** suggests to "*Configuring Bridged Networking Options on a Windows Host*" and [How to set up and manage a Network Bridge connection on Windows 10](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10) says that I need to "*o set a static IP address to your computer manually.*"

**Question:**

Do I really need to go that far?

I am asking this because I did this before on Windows 7 for a school project, and I installed Ubuntu and it worked just fine. Also there was internet (Wi-Fi) on the guest too.

Note:

Guest Additions were installed successfully.

**Edit:**

If I create a new Vm, and choose newer versions of Ubuntu, I get this error right away:

[image]

Comment: 13.04 is really outdated and no longer supported for over 2.5 years now. Please install a supported version like 14.04 or 16.04.

Comment: I see.. I did not know that. Thanks. Is it free?

Comment: Of course it is free. Every Ubuntu release is free.

Comment: @FirstStep - Yes. Get the ISO here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: The official homepage of Ubuntu is http://www.ubuntu.com and the download section for desktop OS is http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop - You'll always find the latest release there.

Comment: Awesome. I will go and try that. Thank you @Byte and Android.

Comment: @ByteCommander I am getting an error when loading the `.iso` file. I will try and download from another source but do you have any idea?

Comment: @AndroidDev Could you also please take a look at the error? Maybe you know. Thanks in advance

Comment: That does not look like a problem with the iso to me. Delete the VM and create it again, maybe that helps. But I do not use Virtualbox on Windows myself, so I'm not sure what exactly it means.

Comment: @FirstStep - I know what the problem is.

Comment: @AndroidDev I chose 4GB RAM, got the error, if I use 2Gb Ram, It launches but I get another error saying: "_The kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU._"

Comment: @FirstStep Can you hop into chat for a second? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a long discussion in chat, we got everything resolved :)

There were multiple issues at play:

- Making sure the OP used a supported LTS release (He was originally using an EOL standard release)
- Making sure the OP's CPU supported VT-X
- Making sure that VT-X was enabled in the BIOS
- Making sure that Hyper-V was disabled, as Hyper-V and VBox cannot coexist
- Making sure that the VM was set to "Ubuntu 64-bit" instead of "Ubuntu 32-bit"
- Making sure the OP knew how to spell Ubuntu :P

In the end, everything was resolved and the VM worked fine.

Comment: And I edited my OP to reflect the correct spelling of Ubuntu my new best friend! :D Thanks again Android Dev! :)

Comment: Got the same issue with a 16.04 host on Win10 just updated to VB 5.1.20.

Initially the guest worked but was unable to go online, I changed the Adapter 1 settings to Network Bridge Adapter (was NAT) and reset the MAC for good measure. It worked fine.

Just to test I reset the network adapter back to NAT and then I got the same black screen issue, setting it back to Bridged it works perfectly.